# Is the language 0^m.0^n , 0<=m<=n regular?

Tags: regex, regular-language, finite-automata, computation-theory

0^m.0^n, . represents concatenation , ^ represents power.

0<=m<=n

My friends are arguing that any string of the form 0* can be broken down conveniently to satisfy the above relation between m and n and hence this should be regular.

While I know that is wrong, I still need to confirm. Thanks

Comment: No, it is not..

Comment: Thank You. Have been arguing with some of my friends, and they are too reluctant to understand

Comment: If that's actually the case here, instead of me just giving you an answer to your homework and you not learning, then you should just show them a pumping lemma proof (which I'm not going to provide).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a computer programming question.

Comment: Haha @Millie , no its not my homework. I have graduated already. I am working for my master's entrance exam.. Thank you for your concern !

Comment: I am not going to use Pumping lemma or myhill nerode or anything for this ... I need them to see logic, I want them to understand that they are doing it in reverse...

Comment: @MillieSmith I think you'll find this language is regular. I encourage you and noobcoder to attempt a pumping-lemma or Myhill-Nerode proof that this language is not regular. Alternatively, prove the following minimal DFA is wrong by providing a counterexample: `Q = {q0}`, `E = {0}`, `q0 = q0`, `A = {q0}`, `f(q0, 0) = q0`.

Comment: @Patrick87 The post has been edited. The only thing in the original post that indicates it was regular is ". represents concatenation". I figured that the dot was an actual part of the language. If the dot is not a part of the alphabet, then this is obviously trivially regular.

Answer (score 0):

Your friends are right, this is regular. With 0<=m you can set m=0. Now for any string 0^k you set k=n. So indeed all strings from 0^* fulfill this condition, and they forma regular language.

Comment: Regardless of the conclusion is right, your logic is missing a step. You're saying that the language 0^* is regular (correct) and all strings in that language are also in the OP's language (correct). You're concluding from this that the OP's language is regular. But that conclusion is not supported by just your earlier claims. You also need all strings in the OP's language to be in 0^*, but didn't cover that in your answer (not that it should be difficult to add).

Comment: Well, @hvd, for a two-way inclusin proof, the argument you mention should indeed be made. But the OP does not even specify the alphabet. If it has only one element, then this part is completely obvious, and even if not it seems too clear to mention that strings consisting only of 0 are all in 0^*.